# Search functionality in 11ty

Tags: javascript, html, eleventy

I am building a basic search functionality on an 11ty site based on this [tutorial](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-create-a-vanilla-js-search-page-for-a-static-website/). My problem is when I type the form and submit it, it will take me to another site even though I included `preventDefault()` in the code. Did I miss out on the steps or is there are better ways of implementing the feature into the site?

Here's my code and link to a demo site:

```js
(function (window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    let form = document.querySelector('#form-search');
    let input = document.querySelector('#search-input');
    let resultList = document.querySelector('#search-results');

    /**
     * Create the HTML for each result
     * @param  {Object} article The article
     * @param  {Number} id      The result index
     * @return {String}         The markup
     */
    let createHTML = function (article, id) {
        let html =
            '<div id="search-result-' + id + '">' +
                '<a href="' + article.url + '">' +
                    '<aside>' +
                        article.date +
                    '</aside>' +
                    '<h2>' + article.title + '</h2>' +
                    article.summary.slice(0, 150) + '...<br>' +
                    article.url +
                '</a>' +
            '</div>';
        return html;
    };

    /**
     * Create the markup when no results are found
     * @return {String} The markup
     */
    let createNoResultsHTML = function () {
        return '<p>Sorry, no matches were found.</p>';
    };

    /**
     * Create the markup for results
     * @param  {Array} results The results to display
     * @return {String}        The results HTML
     */
    let createResultsHTML = function (results) {
        let html = '<p>Found ' + results.length + ' matching articles</p>';
        html += results.map(function (article, index) {
            return createHTML(article, index);
        }).join('');
        return html;
    };

    /**
     * Search for matches
     * @param  {String} query The term to search for
     */
    let search = function (query) {

        // Variables
        let reg = new RegExp(query, 'gi');
        let priority1 = [];
        let priority2 = [];

        // Search the content
        searchIndex.forEach(function (article) {
            if (reg.test(article.title)) return priority1.push(article);
            if (reg.test(article.blogTitle)) priority2.push(article);
        });

        // Combine the results into a single array
        let results = [].concat(priority1, priority2);

        // Display the results
        resultList.innerHTML = results.length < 1 ? createNoResultsHTML() : createResultsHTML(results);

    };

    /**
     * Handle submit events
     */
    let submitHandler = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        search(input.value);
    };

    // Make sure required content exists
    if (!form || !input || !resultList || !searchIndex) return;

    // Create a submit handler
    form.addEventListener('submit', submitHandler);

})(window, document);
```

```html
<section id="hero">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hero-buttons">
        <h1 class="blog-header">11ty Search Demo</h1>
        <form action="https://duckduckgo.com/" method="get" id="form-search">
            <input class="search-input" placeholder="Search here..." />
            <input type="hidden" name="sites" value="https://11ty-search-demo.netlify.app/">
            <button class="submit-search">Search</button>
        </form>
        <div id="search-results"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="blog">
    <div class="container">
        {%- for post in collections.post | reverse -%} {% include
        'recent-snippet.njk' %} {%- endfor -%}
    </div>
</section>
```

Demo link: https://11ty-search-demo.netlify.app/

Code Sandbox: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/mohammedasker/search-demo/11ty-Search-Demo?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.njk&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cl9qnqrsj000eltev9vt67fa5%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.njk%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A8080%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl9tj8wvp00ag356h5q35xry1%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After debugging the code, the issue was traced to the following line:

```js
if (!form || !input || !resultList || !searchIndex) return;
```

In this segment, you are checking whether any of the values in the **`if`** condition are **`false`**. If that's the case, the function will either return **`false`** or **`undefined`**. The problem arises because your **`input`** variable is **`undefined`**, causing the entire function to evaluate as **`false`**. Consequently, the subsequent line of code fails to execute:

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', submitHandler);
```

This unexecuted line is responsible for handling the form submission. As a result, your form is being submitted unexpectedly.

The reason behind the **`input`** variable being **`undefined`** lies in the selector you used. Instead of using an **`id`**, you mistakenly used a **`class`** selector. For instance, you used this:

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#search-input');
```

However, it should be like this:

```js
let input = document.querySelector('.search-input');
```

This corrected selector targets the element with the class name **`search-input`**, ensuring that the **`input`** variable receives the intended element.

To visualize the solution in action, you can refer to this functional [example](https://codepen.io/ankit25821/pen/oNyjaeK).